# Java: How to get set of keys having same value in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap as below:

1->x

2->y

3->x

4->z

Now i want to know all keys whose value is x (ans: [1,3] ). what is best way to do?

Brute force way is to just iterate over map and store all keys in array whose value is x.

Is there any efficient way for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [`MultiMap`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps) to easily get all those duplicate values.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "x");
map.put(2, "y");
map.put(2, "z");
map.put(3, "x");
map.put(4, "y");
map.put(5, "z");
map.put(6, "x");
map.put(7, "y");

System.out.println("Original map: " + map);

Multimap<String, Integer> multiMap = HashMultimap.create();
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  multiMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}
System.out.println();

for (Entry<String, Collection<Integer>> entry : multiMap.asMap().entrySet()) {
  System.out.println("Original value: " + entry.getKey() + " was mapped to keys: "
      + entry.getValue());
}
```

Prints out:

```
Original map: {1=x, 2=z, 3=x, 4=y, 5=z, 6=x, 7=y}

Original value: z was mapped to keys: [2, 5]
Original value: y was mapped to keys: [4, 7]
Original value: x was mapped to keys: [1, 3, 6]
```

Per @**noahz**'s suggestion, `forMap` and `invertFrom` takes fewer lines, but is arguably more complex to read:

```
HashMultimap<String, Integer> multiMap =
    Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(map), 
        HashMultimap.<String, Integer> create());
```

in place of:

```
Multimap<String, Integer> multiMap = HashMultimap.create();
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  multiMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: Question stated that he "already had a `HashMap`. Therefore `Multimaps.forMap()` and `invertFrom()` is a much more concise solution.

Comment: Dunno about "much more concise" considering it reduces it by one line, but I updated to reflect your answer as well.

Answer (score 13):

A hashmap is a structure that is optimized for associative access of the values using the keys, but is in no way better in doing the reverse then an array for instance. I don't think you can do any better then just iterate. Only way to improve efficiency is if you have a reverse hash map as well(i.e. hash map where you hold an array of keys pointing to a given value for all values).

Comment: That's right. Any other utilities would also iterate if provided only a HashMap.

Answer (score 8):

If Java 8 is an option, you could try a streaming approach:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "x");
map.put(2, "y");
map.put(3, "x");
map.put(4, "z");

Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> reverseMap = new HashMap<>(
    map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue)).values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                item -> item.get(0).getValue(),
                item -> new ArrayList<>(
                    item.stream()
                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ))
        ));

System.out.println(reverseMap);
```

Which results in:

```
{x=[1, 3], y=[2], z=[4]}
```

If Java 7 is preferred:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> reverseMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (!reverseMap.containsKey(entry.getValue())) {
        reverseMap.put(entry.getValue(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> keys = reverseMap.get(entry.getValue());
    keys.add(entry.getKey());
    reverseMap.put(entry.getValue(), keys);
}
```

As an interesting aside, I experimented with the time required for each algorithm when executing large maps of (index,random('a'-'z') pairs.

```
              10,000,000        20,000,000
Java 7:         615 ms            11624 ms         
Java 8:        1579 ms             2176 ms
```

Comment: Cannot infer type arguments for Hashmap<>

Comment: It's giving error "Cannot infer type arguments for Hashmap<>"

Answer (score 6):

If you are open to using a library, use [Google Guava's Multimaps utilities](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps), specifically `forMap()` combined with `invertFrom()`

Answer (score 4):

Yup, just brute force. You can make it fast by also storing a Multimap from Value -> Collection of Key, at the expense of memory and runtime cost for updates.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` computes the `hashcode()` of the key, not of the values. Unless you store some kind of additional information, or consider using a different data structure, I think the only way you can get this is brute force.

If you need to perform efficient operation on the values, you should think whether you're using the appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a hashmap there is no efficient way doing it but iterating the values

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a map, you should consider using [Google's Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) library to filter the entries you're interested in. You can do something along the lines of:

```
final Map<Integer, Character> filtered = Maps.filterValues(unfiltered, new Predicate<Character>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Character ch) {
        return ch == 'x';
    }
});
```

Comment: Or...perhaps `Multimaps.forMap()` which when combined with `invertFrom()` does exactly what the questioner is requesting?

Comment: Nice solution, I'll remember that in future.

Comment: If you only want keys for a particular value (which is what OP asked for), this solution is best; no need to create two `MultiMap`s along the way. Note that you don't have to write your own predicate; just use `Maps.filterValues(unfiltered, Predicates.equalTo('x')).keySet()`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with George Campbell but for java 8 I would do it a bit easier:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> reverseMap = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Technically this should a `Collectors.toSet()` instead of a `Collectors.toList()`

Answer (score -1):

Try This.....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashMap.put("cust_tenure", "3_sigma");
        hashMap.put("cust_age", "3_sigma");
        hashMap.put("cust_amb_6m_sav", "3_sigma");
        hashMap.put("cust_amb_6m_chq", "3_sigma");
        hashMap.put("cust_total_prod_6m", "3_sigma");

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> colName = null;
            if (!result.containsKey(hashMap.get(key))) {
                colName = new ArrayList<String>();
                colName.add(key);
                result.put(hashMap.get(key), colName);
            } else {
                colName = result.get(hashMap.get(key));
                colName.add(key);
                result.put(hashMap.get(key), colName);
            }

            System.out.println(key + "\t" + hashMap.get(key));
        }

        for (String key : result.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + result.get(key));
        }

        System.out.println(hashMap.size());

    }
```