# Identify the Key-Value pair having duplicate values

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, multimap

I have a multimap like below:

```
{20014=[13123], 20013=[45451, 13123]}
```

where the keys and values are in `String`

If there is any duplicate in the value from other key, I have to print that key-value pair. In this case, it will be Key-20013,Value-13123.

How to achieve this?
I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710494/java-how-to-get-set-of-keys-having-same-value-in-hashmap) but not getting how to get the duplicate  pair.

Comment: Which Multimap ? the guava one?

Comment: Yes the guava one.

Comment: Why not key-20014, value-13123 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
// Initialize my multimap
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put("20014", "13123");
multimap.put("20013", "45451");
multimap.put("20013", "13123");

// Set in which we store the values to know if they exist already
Set<String> allValues = new HashSet<>();
// Convert the multimap into a Map
Map<String, Collection<String>> map = multimap.asMap();
// Iterate over the existing entries
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Collection<String> values =  entry.getValue();
    // Iterate over the existing values for a given key
    for (String value : values) {
        // Check if the value has already been defined if so print a log message
        if (!allValues.add(value)) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Key-%s,Value-%s", key, value));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key-20013,Value-13123
```

Comment: In my case the key and value both are duplicate how can I fetch the duplicate pair(including key and value)

Answer (score 1):

You can invert your multimap and, viewed as a map, iterate through its entries:

```
Multimap<String, String> inverse = Multimaps.invertFrom(multimap, HashMultimap.create());
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : inverse.asMap().entrySet()) {
    String value = entry.getKey();
    Iterator<String> keysIterator = entry.getValue().iterator();
    assert keysIterator.hasNext() : "there is always at least one key";
    keysIterator.next(); // skip first key
    while (keysIterator.hasNext()) { // each additional key is a duplicate
        String key = keysIterator.next();
        System.out.println(String.format("Key-%s,Value-%s", key, value));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key-20013,Value-13123
```

If you are using an [`ImmutableMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html) then instead of [`Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimap, M)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom(com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M)) you can simply use [`ImmutableMultimap.inverse()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html#inverse()):

```
ImmutableMultimap<String, String> inverse = multimap.inverse();
```

If you simply want a map of duplicated values to their respective keys then you can use [`Maps.filterValues(Map, Predicate)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterValues(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)):

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> keysByDuplicatedValue = Maps.filterValues(inverse.asMap(),
        keys -> keys.size() > 1);
```

Which will give you  a map like below:

```
{13123=[20014, 20013]}
```